# javascript submit form from function

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
    var changedate  = document.getElementById("date");

    changedate.onchange = submitform;

    function submitform() {
    document.forms["form"].submit();

    }
```

However I have 3 submit buttons in my form, I want to call the submit button with ID 'save' with this function.
How, can I do this, because at the moment when I change the value in 'date' the form gets submitted, but not in the way i manually push the submit button 'save' at the bottom of the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

where myForm is id of your form.

Comment: Tried that, but strangely nothing happens right then.

Comment: Please try document.getElementById("date").addEventListener("change", function(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}); Please make sure that there is not duplicate ID. with form id.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<input type="hidden" name="submitbutton">` . In each button, before submitting set the value of this hidden field accordingly. In the code executed when date is changed, set the hidden value as how you set for the `save` button Eg:

```
<form method="post" action="something.php">
    <input type="submit" value="save" onsubmit="setType('save');return true;"/>
    <input type="submit" value="btn2" onsubmit="setType('btn2');return true;"/>
    <input type="submit" value="btn3" onsubmit="setType('btn3');return true;"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdn" value=""/>
</form>
```

In your js,

```
function setType(msg){document.getElementById('hdn').value=msg;}
```

and when date is changed,

```
setType('save');
document.forms["form"].submit();
```

Make sure you catch correctly in your php/asp file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes after submitting the form:

There is a part:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {

// do something 
}
?>
```

This is not executed because I dont click on the submit button 'save' in the form.